# If I have the equation of a line, how do I find a point on that line that is a specific distance from another?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have two points and I need to create a line that is perpendicular to the line they form. Also the intersection has to be 5 (units) away from the first point. I know how to get a perpendicular line but not how to get the point on the first line that is 5 units away from the first point.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static function distanceFromPoint(a:Point, b:Point, dist:Number):Point {
    var tmp:Point = b.subtract(a);
    tmp.normalize(dist);
    return a.add(tmp);
}
```

**How this works:**
You subtract `a` from `b` to get the vector between the two points.  You normalize this vector and multiply it by `dist` to get a line `dist` units long pointing in the direction from `a` to `b`.  Add this vector to point `a` and the result will be a new point that is `dist` units from `a` in the direction of `b`.

Comment: +1. A minor note. You should use a temporary variable to store the normalized point, since `normalize` returns `void`. Something like this: `public static function distanceFromPoint(a:Point, b:Point, dist:Number):Point { var tmp:Point = b.subtract(a); tmp.normalize(dist); return a.add(tmp);}`

Comment: Thanks @Juan.  I modded up [one of your underrated answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217212/key-value-pairs-in-as3/3217584#3217584) in return.

Answer (score 0):

use the equation of a circle centered on the first point, and solve for x and y.

first point = x_0, y_0

equation of a circle of radius 5 around first point

(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = 25

use the equation of the line to replace y, and solve for x. Careful that you get 2 points, pick the right one. The use the equation of the line again to solve for y.